# I used "Contact Form 7 - InfusionSoft Add-on" wordpress plugin for store contact form mail to "infusionsoft" CRM but it not work

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, plugins

I want to store contact form 7 mail to "Infusionsoft" CRM and for this i used "Contact Form 7 - InfusionSoft Add-on" wordpress plugin and i also integrate "Infusionsoft" API key and App name but it not works
Please help me, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it somehow works, then you`re good to go.
Another alternative, no matter the software is to make use of Zapier. You could create a zap to move a database row(your contact forms submitted and saved to database) to Infusionsoft or any other CRM.

You could use a plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/ for saving contact forms to database.

Thanks!